# include PHP in an HTML

Tags: javascript, php

I already work all the code but with PHP, some way to pass it to HTML and manipulate it with CSS ?, This shows me in real time, but I need to accommodate them in an HTML that I already have with a Video.

```js
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");

    $valor1 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor2 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='BANREP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor3 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='ICAP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor4 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor5 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor6 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='DTF']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor7 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='UVR']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor8 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    $valor9 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TIB']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;

?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK7FT.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your PHP code looks good, but in your question you are asking how to pass it to HTML. We can't answer that question without knowing more about where you want this to happen (maybe on a server?). We would need to know more about the HTML, and technologies that you would/could consider using (ex. jQuery, Apache, AWS, something else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");

$valor1 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor2 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='BANREP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor3 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='ICAP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor4 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor5 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor6 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='DTF']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor7 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='UVR']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor8 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
echo "<br>";
$valor9 = $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TIB']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;

$myArray = [$valor1,$valor2,$valor3,$valor4,$valor5,$valor6,$valor7,$valor8,$valor9]
?>

<html>
<body>


<?php foreach($myArray as $data): ?>
<label><?php echo $data; ?></label>
<br />
<?php endforeach; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is just a quick example of how you can insert php output inside HTML. You can use any html element you want and of course style it with css.

I inserted your variables into an array so i can actually use a loop for it but if you don't find the loop useful or handy for you then you can simple `echo` every variable you already have.